# Changes occur only on refresh after re-direct on posting a form a php

Tags: php, forms, session, post

I have a page where users post form. It's in `php`.

If a user is already logged in, the form is not shown.
If a user is not logged in, the form is shown.

Now, when a user first visits the site, the form is shown. Then he fills the form and `submits` it as `POST`. On successful login, he is re-directed to the same page.

The problem is, after been re-directed to the same page, the form is still visible. Though, if I refresh it, the form disappears.

How can I change/modify to achieve what I want.

I don't know if giving my code will be helpful or not. Though, according to SO I'm attaching my basic code:

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    //show form
    <form action="" method="post">
        <br><button class="lfloat" type="submit" id="submit" value="register0" name="submit">Register</button><br><br>
    </form>
    <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['submit']=='register0'){
        //do all the insertion of data into database here only.
        ....
        ....
        echo "Success!!";
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    //don't show form

}
```

Comment: where in your code do you set $_SESSION['id'] ?

Comment: @John: In the starting of the page i've included:`session_start();`

Comment: yes, but where do you set $_SESSION['id'] ? After the form is posted? Can you include that in your example code?

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['submit']=='register0'){
        //do all the insertion of data into database here only.
        ....
        ....
        echo "Success!!";
$_SESSION['id'] = 'some value';
header(Location: 'yourForm.php');
exit;

    }
```

should work for you...also dont forget to write

```
session_start();
```

at the top of your form.php

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

```
<?php $hideForm = isset($_SESSION['id']); ?>

<form action="" method="post" style="<?= $hideForm ? 'display:none;' : '' ?>" >
...
```

or even more concisely:

```
<form action="" method="post" style="<?= isset($_SESSION['id']) ? 'display:none;' : '' ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is true that you save the ID in the database, but I don't see that you reload the page, so it is not there in `SESSION` after you save the ID.

You could do `<form action="pageURL.php?action=save">` once you saved the new information, but then maybe you should need to do a switch and pass by query string an action so the post doesn't resubmit on refresh. The idea would be to use this pattern: [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Then your page would look something like this:

```
$action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

switch ($action) {
    case 'save':
        //Do your the registration and then
        header('Location:YourPagePath.php?action=saved');
        break;
    case 'save':
        /*FALL TRHOUGH*/
    default:
        //The rest of the page code
        break;
}
```

Also, the fast but not that good of a solution would be, on successful log in:

```
echo '<script>
    alert("Save successful");
    location.href="YourPagePath.php"
</script>';
exit;
```